# Удаление файла внутренней памяти deleteFile() выдает ошибку

Tags: android

Пробую удалить файл:

```
deleteFile(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileNamePath);
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
File /data/user/0/ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook/files/filesPath.json contains a path separator
```

Как поправить?

Comment: Попробуйте `new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileNamePath).delete()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеется в виду метод `Context.deleteFile(String name)` - то он принимает только имя файла (без полного пути), так как его работа рассчитана только на файлы приватной папки приложения (которую возвращает `getFilesDir()`).
Для Вашего случая:

```
  deleteFile(fileNamePath);
```